# Facebook link sharing/Debugger refuses connection to TLS 1.2 website

Tags: facebook

(According to https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/ there are Facebook engineers reading this.)

Some of our web hosting customers recently complained about missing images/text when sharing content from their https website to Facebook.

I tracked this problem to a security change in our environment that disabled TLS v1.0 for customer HTTPS sites. The curl output in Facebook Debugger merely showed an SSL connection error and I can reproduce the problem locally if I force curl to not try TLS v1.1 nor v1.2.

These values in Apache 2.4 vhost configuration makes Facebook not connect to my customers site:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1
```

Changing SSLProtocol to this make Facebook work OK:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

'All' includes TLS v1.1 and v1.2. Why doesn't Facebook link-sharing and the Facebook Debugger work against modern sites that use TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2 (and have SSLv3 & TLSv1 disabled)?

Thanks.

Comment: You’ll likely have a better chance of getting this resolved by filing a bug report under https://developers.facebook.com/bugs However I suggest you put the site through some of the SSL checking services available on the web beforehand, just to make sure it is definitively not a problem on your end.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I've run the customer sites through SSL Labs' checker and they come through at grade A. If I add '-TLSv1' to the Apache vhost keyword 'SSLProtocol All -SSLv3', sharing links via Facebook doesn't include text or images from the site. Looks like that bugs site requires a Facebook account, though. I'll see if I can get someone to open a bug for me.